# Design Custom Android ViewGroup Subclasses

Tags: android, layout

Android Developer has a nice discussion on writing your own View subclasses:
   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

But I want to write my own ViewGroup *subclass* with my own child positioning policy.  Where is there a minimal example of this kind of thing? (This is a Java *coding* question not an XML one)

Specifically I want a horizontal layout that (like LinearLayout) fills in children from the left - *but* once the horizontal space is consumed, shifts the children to the left so that the **last child** appears aligned to the **right end** of the layout.  The children are button-like and so a HorzontalScrollView does not work since the scrolling gesture clicks the buttons instead of moving them.

If LinearLayout has an option to do this, I could not find it.

Answer (score 10):

`HorizontalScrollView` should work, scrolling should not click the buttons. But if you really want to write your own custom layout, have a look at this [archive](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B_VKZCqEnHblNDdiY2UxODgtYWNhNS00MmU4LWE4NDMtZjQ1OWI5MDMxZTVh&sort=name&layout=list&num=50&pli=1) (the [video](http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=2191&sl=0) is also available)

Comment: I typed the code from the video since I couldn't find it on the web. Can you put a description somewhere on the download page for "FlowLayout" Devoxx. That would have save me 1hr of typing. :)